# UICollectionView change layout with custom animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have two collectionViewLayout, verticalFlowLayout and fullScreenHorizontalFlowLayout.

```
@implementation VerticalFlowLayout
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 0, 0, 0);
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), 244);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

---

```
@implementation FullScreenFlowLayout
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds));
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    }
    return self;
}
```

when I select a cell I want to change collectionView layout with **custom animation**. default animation is a linear animation with 0.33 duration.

```
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([_collectionView.collectionViewLayout isKindOfClass:[FullScreenFlowLayout class]]) {
        VerticalFlowLayout *flowLayout = [VerticalFlowLayout new];
        [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }
    else
        [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:[FullScreenFlowLayout new] animated:YES];

}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap `_collectionView.collectionViewFlowLayout = flowLayout` in a `UIView` animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        // Do Something
    }
}];
```

Comment: here is a complete guide in custom collectionView layout animation: https://github.com/cnoon/CollectionViewAnimations

Comment: I think it's super awesome you went from asking about how to do this, to creating a well documented GitHub repo for other people to reference. Great job.